# How to return associated model objects in Rails with ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Let's assume I have the following three objects:

```
class Filing < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :company
    has_many :people , :dependent => :destroy
end

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :filings
end

class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :filing
end
```

I'm attempting to make **a single request that returns the filing with it's associated company and an array containing it's associated people**.  This is being used for an API request of GET filing/:id

I saw the documentation on [joining tables with ActiveRecord](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables), however when I run the following query:

```
Filing.joins(:people,:company)
```

It doesn't appear to include the associated people or company in the result set.  I'm kind of confused about why I would do a join if the associated data won't be returned.  What am I missing here?  What query should I be running?

**Update**

As mentioned in the comments.  I want to be able to generate the following output:

```
{ "filing" => { "filing_id" => 123, "company" => { ... }, "people" => [{"person_id" => 1}, {"person_id" => 2}] } }
```

Comment: This query `Filing.joins(:people,:company)` will return all Fillings that have a company and at least one people associated with. What do you want exactly at the end? An Array like following `[Filling, Category, [People]]` ?

Comment: If you want all of the people associated with a Filing, you could just do `@f = Filing.where('id = ?', some_id).people` and for the company, `@f.company` should work

Comment: You might be looking for `includes`

Comment: @bdares is correct ... I'm looking for includes.  However so far I can only get one include (e.g. Filing.first(:include => company)).  How do I include two?  MrYoshiji, the end result that I want is { "filing" => {"filing_id" => 123, "company" => { ... }, "people" => [{"person_id" => 1,...}, {"person_id" => 2}] } }

Comment: After additional searching, it appears that this will return the desired result: Filing.find(756 , :include => [:company,:people])

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the help of commenters I ended up finding the answer.  All that needs to be called is:

```
Filing.find( id , :include => [:company,:people] )
```

Comment: You should realize that this executes multiple queries, one for each table.  However, it is still reasonably efficient.

Comment: Fair point, however I'm not sure how I would do it with one massive join request, or whether that join request would actually be more efficient.

Comment: Is there a more dynamic way to do this? Like return every association for Filing without explicitly naming the other tables?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is the following:

```
Filing.includes([:company, :people]).where(:filing => [:id => 756])
```

Comment: Include is not a valid method, I believe you mean includes.

Comment: Fixed.  Thanks @Siraris.